# how can I call a webservice from voiceXML?

Tags: web-services, voicexml

I'm building a very simple voiceXML app to allow people to make recordings.
But first, I need to authenticate callers by phone number and/or PIN.

Can I call a webservice from voiceXML? Looks like I want to use the voiceXML "data" element to call my webservice. However, I need to dynamically calculate the URL, and it looks like it only takes a static string as the "src" parameter.

I'm new to voiceXML, so pointing me to a good tutorial would help too! I'm working from the voxeo documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're right about needing the data element, and i'd have a look at the screxpr attribute of that element.

https://web.archive.org/web/20131007104119/http://www.vxml.org/frame.jsp?page=data.htm

pretty self-explanatory:

```
<data srcexpr="'http://example.com/?key=' + myValue" />
```

Comment: Your link is dead

Comment: Found it in the wayback machine.